# PlasticSCM - administration using console

Tags: plasticscm

In attempting to identify which users have licenses I run a command prompt and execute "CM LI" and the command line sits waiting and never returns.  How do I even begin to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to specify explicitly the server location:

cm licenseinfo --server=yourserver:8087

Alternatively you can enable the client and server log in order to identify the issue (Why the command is not finishing).

http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/kb-enabling-logging-for-plastic-scm-part-i.aspx

you can also ask for help in the Plastic SCM forum: www.plasticscm.net